# stuck funds in smart contract //Remix // Solidity

Tags: bots, solidity, remix

i did a smart contract in remix and then send funds and clicked start.
Then my balance went to 0 Ether. Is there a possibility to get it back?

Here is the video i used:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFHZUn7X52Y&

was it a scam or did i just had bad luck?
The guy made the video said it's stuck in the mempool router adress becaus ethe network was to busy and my 1 ether couldn't create enough slippage.

then he said i can solve this if i send the exact same amount again to reset the bot. (routing duplicstion) but that sounds like a scam. Maybe my money is lost, but if someone can really help me i will thank him with 0.1 ether.

here is my contract adress:
https://etherscan.io/address/0x70f8441337677BA13552E8FC3f956FFB7f078451

the code will be found in the youtube description.

best regards and thanks in advance.
Marcus

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because StackOverflow is not a support site for cryptocurrency scam victims.

Comment: Please don't post links to code. Instead, include the relevant parts of the code (formatted as a code block) directly in your question. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Posts in which code is only present in links are likely to be closed as lacking enough details, as they can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

### **Do not send any more ether to the contract, THIS IS A SCAM !**

Sorry to break it to you but this looks like another uniswap bot contract scam .. just by looking at the video, the crazy amounts he's claiming to return, and comments on the video you can definitly say that something fishy is going on.. I got the owner's telegram handler from his youtube and I pretended that I had a smiliar issue as yours and I got the same answer, he wanted me to send more eth, so here is that.

Scams of these genres are very popular and everyone should be aware of! the contract you deployed imports another one from the IPFS that allows the scammer to steal your funds once you deposit them into this UniSwap contract and there's no way to get it back.